Kubuntu 24.04 fails to use Android mobile hotspot
Kubuntu 24.04, freshly installed, fails to use the internet provided by my Android phone's Wi-Fi hotspot. Other devices work fine with it. Ping works, but not DNS resolution. Any way to fix or diagnose the problem is appreciated. My home Wi-Fi works on this Kubuntu device.
admin@samsung-laptop:~$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

admin@samsung-laptop:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=70.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=87.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=67.7 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 67.741/75.362/87.480/8.662 ms

admin@samsung-laptop:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 194.158.206.205
nameserver 194.158.206.206
nameserver fe80::1%wlan0

admin@samsung-laptop:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:b7:c3:69:e0:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:b7:c3:48:e1:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.203.188/24 brd 192.168.203.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp5s0
       valid_lft 3557sec preferred_lft 3557sec


Can you try USB tether to the phone and see if DNS works then?

@Jeremy31 doesn't work the same way
